# GTX1080 gpu passthrough Qemu

Tags: nvidia, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

Never had a problem passing through a Titan with QEMU, I've replaced it with a GTX1080 and cant seem to get it to display anything.
`vfio` is doing it's thing:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1b80] (rev a1)
Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:119e]
Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10f0] (rev a1)
Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:119e]
Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
```

When I try to run a VM I get the black screen of nothingness, as if the card is being passed through correctly but VGA can't initialize for some reason  The only real addition (aside from the the new card) is this "Subsystem". The Titan didn't specify an address for a "Subsystem".

This is the code I'm running, in an attempt to get it to even show the BIOS.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-smp sockets=1,cores=4,threads=1 \
-enable-kvm \
-cpu host,kvm=off \
-m 16000 \
-vga none \
-device vfio-pci,host=03:00.0,multifunction=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=03:00.1 \
-hda windows.qcow2 \
```

Do you you guy's have any tips to help me? QEMU doesnt give any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

It is working now. Had to switch to using OVMF bios and q35 chipset.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-smp sockets=1,cores=4,threads=1 \
-M q35 \
-bios /usr/share/qemu/bios.bin \
-enable-kvm \
-cpu host,kvm=off \
-m 16000 \
-vga none \
-device vfio-pci,host=03:00.0,multifunction=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=03:00.1 \
-hda windows.qcow2 \
```